# Should you completely avoid const in templated code?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

The idea of writing templated code is to write generic code that easily applies to some generic type `T`.

The idea of using `const` is to *impose behavior* upon objects. It's not just a matter of telling users how they can or cannot use an object, but it's also about telling the object *itself* that it cannot change.

These two ideas seem to contradict, do they not? How can you write generic code while simultaneously making assumptions about the *constness* of the generic type? Sure, in many cases you might be able to predict that you'll never instantiate your code with a type that won't comply with your `const`-usage, but imagine the horror if you suddenly found out that's not the case, and would have to dig through all of your code to remove wrongly placed `const`?

How do we solve this problem? Do we just not write `const` in templated code?

Answer (score 5):

`const` certainly has its place. Take for instance `vector::operator[]`, which is there as a twofold overload:

1. `T &operator[](size_t offset)` gives you a mutable reference to the data.
2. `T const &operator[](size_t offset) const` gives you a const reference.

When I use a `vector<int>`, I might want to have a `vector<int> const` and if it wan't for the second overload, I could not access any elements in it.

One has to be mindful where to place `const`s, but they also have their place in template code.

Answer (score 1):

No. `const` is sometimes about how a particular piece of code will use an object. `void f(const T&)` says that `f` won’t modify its argument.

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting question though to be plain honest I have the feeling that you approach the question with some false premises.

First, "generic" does not mean that generic code must work for any type `T` that can possibly exist. To the contrary, generic code usually tells you what are the requirements on `T` to make the code do what it is supposed to do.

For example, `T` must be CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible otherwise you cannot instantiate a [`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). `T` must be destructible, otherwise you cannot instantiate a [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). Etc.

Seoncd, most `const` actually does refer to how the instance is used (as opposed to what the instance actually is).

As an example, consider

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T& t) {
    std::cout << t;
}
```

This template can only be instantiated if there exists an `operator<<` overload that takes a `const T&`. Now if a type does not fullfil this requirement, then you cannot instantiate the method for that type.

Note that if some type `Foo` breaks this requirement by only having a

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Foo&);
```

then removing the `const` from `print` is not a solution, because then suddenly it would be impossible to call `print` with any other `const T&`. Declaring print to not modify its parameters is a completely valid use of `const` in templated code.